# Erro no meu Programa em C

Tags: c

Quando digito `0` ele não informa conforme o programa devia: "Entrada incorreta. Digite um valor inteiro".

```
#include <stdio.h>

void LimpaBuffer(void)
{  
    int valorLido; /* valorLido deve ser int */
    do {
        valorLido = getchar();
       } while((valorLido = '\n') && (valorLido !=EOF));
}
int main(void)
{
    int umInt, outroInt, nValoresLidos;
    printf("Digite um valor inteiro");
    nValoresLidos = scanf("%d", &umInt);
    while(nValoresLidos == 0) { //Nenhum inteiro for lido
        LimpaBuffer();
        printf("Entrada incorreta. Digite um valor inteiro");
        nValoresLidos = scanf("%d", &umInt);
    }
    printf("Digite outro valor inteiro");
    nValoresLidos = scanf("%d", &outroInt);
    while (nValoresLidos == 0) {
        LimpaBuffer();
        printf("Entrada incorreta. Digite um valor inteiro");
        nValoresLidos = scanf("%d", &outroInt);

    }
    printf("\n%d + %d = %d", umInt, outroInt, umInt + outroInt);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Descobri o problema da sua pergunta, falta um `!=` em vez de `=` em `while((valorLido = '\n') &&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No loop `while` você está checando o `nValoresLidos`, mas o `scanf` não atribui o valor a `nValoresLidos` e sim a `outroInt`.

Faça assim:

```
scanf("%d", &outroInt);
nValoresLidos = outroInt;
```

Comment: Fiz igualizinho como no livro.

Comment: A edição do livro é a mais recente? Se for, pode mandar a correção para o autor, ele deve ter algum meio pra isso, que fica no próprio livro.

Comment: O livro é de 2008 Programando em C - Volume I - Ulysses de Oliveira

Comment: Infelizmente a maioria dos livros de programação são muito ruins. O pessoal não tem o mínimo cuidado nos exemplos que podem ser facilmente verificado. Imagine se você pode confiar nas outras informações mais difíceis de avaliar se está certo ou não quando está aprendendo.

Comment: @bigown este exemplo funciona como deve ser, vê a minha resposta.

Comment: @JorgeB. não tinha visto sua resposta ainda, tá corrido. Mas fiquei confuso está correto ou precisa corrigir? Na primeira parte você diz que está correto e depois diz que faltou um `not`. De qualquer forma fica o registro porque muitos livros estão errados mesmo :)

Comment: @bigown falta um `not` (que até poderá ter sido engano do AP a copiar do livro, não sei) , mas o problema do autor é outro, ele quer que apareça a mensagem de erro quando digitar `0`, mas não coincide com o funcionamento do programa, porque `0` também é um inteiro.

Comment: Assim sendo `while (nValoresLidos == 0)` quer dizer "enquanto não for digitado um inteiro dá erro e lê de novo"

Answer (score 5):

Esse programa está correto. O que está errado é a forma do AP pensar.

O `while(nValoresLidos == 0)` quer dizer:

**Enquanto o `scanf` não ler, neste caso, um `%d` dá erro de leitura!**

Por exemplo se digitar:

```
Digite um valor inteiro
0
Digite outro um valor inteiro
1

0 + 1 = 1
```

Está corretíssimo.

Neste caso o '0' não é uma forma errada no *input*.

---

**[Edit]**

Para além disso nesta linha falta um `!`:

```
} while((valorLido = '\n') && (valorLido !=EOF));
```

deveria ser :

```
} while((valorLido != '\n') && (valorLido !=EOF));
```

Assim já funcionará corretamente.